# Would beings with a base 8 number system be advantaged for electronics?

Tags: dragons, computers, mathematics, numeral

I am looking forward to create anthropomorphic dragons/lizards with 8 fingers (3 + thumb). As they base their number system on it, the powers of 2 are recurrent.

Would this grant any advantage for the understanding of electronics and the math behind them? Would they create machines faster than humans?

Comment: There's no guarantee that electronics would be binary, or that computation would even require electronics. Babbage almost succeeded at steampunk computation (which was going to be base-10). Many many design decisions were laid down early that could have been made differently and everything after is just based off of those.

Comment: @John - If they used analog computers first (as we did) then digits don't matter. However once you decide to have on-off logic (the easiest sort to implement), binary or trinary is inevitable. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_computer

Comment: Related : https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/153914/number-of-fingers-for-a-math-oriented-race

Comment: @chasly-reinstateMonica Binary isn't inevitable. It just looks like it with hindsight. Babbage's computer wasn't analog at all... and it was going to be base-10. Even in electronics, other number bases are possible... and if the species decides to go with those first, they soon gain the expertise to take it further, and they'd be saying things like "of course trinary is inevitable!".

Comment: @John - While you were typing, I edited to include ternary!

Comment: @JohnO other base numbers are possible through software. The transistors in your CPU are binary. The lowest forms of programming have to be too, by necessity.

Comment: @Renan Other bases are possible through hardware. They're just not practical once you've got 80 years of binary electronics experience. But then, some species that did trinary would probably say the same thing about binary.

Comment: @Renan - not necesarily - see this link - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_computer

Comment: I don't understand the question -- we use base ten in ordinary life, and yet we have exactly zero trouble understanding Boolean logic, binary arithmetic and the like. Many people of a certain age who work in IT have even retained the ability to do mental calculations in hexadecimal, octal or both, depending on what was the convention on the systems they worked with in the seventies and eighties. So that I don't get what is meant by "an advantage"; certainly not any significant advantage of the ten fingered humans.

Comment: @AlexP, The advantage is that every single last literate person would be able to easily do mental calculations in octal.

Comment: @cowlinator: Every single numerate person **is** able to do mental calculations in octal *if they need to* for their work. It's not a superhuman feat, it's not even hard to learn.

Comment: In a word, no. I used to work on the PDP-11. which had a lot of octal around, and it was nothing but a pain in the neck, even though I could do octal arithmetic in my head and all that. My subsequent move to hexadecimal was most welcome.

Comment: @Renan, transistors are not binary. In fact, they're not even "digital." A transistor, like a light dimmer, can be "on" or it can be "off" or it can be anywhere in-between. The problem is, if you want to _use_ transistors in the most power-efficient way, then you want to avoid the "in-between" region. Modern, binary logic circuits allow practically no current to flow when an output that is either fully on or fully off is connected to one or more inputs. But, there must be substantial current flow in any transistor that is in an "in-between" state.

Comment: Just a minor note: Number systems don't necessarily have to be derived from [counting fingers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger-counting#Other_Body-Based_Counting_Systems). Some alternatives include counting spaces between fingers for base-8 (historically happened in California and Mexico), counting a variety of points across the body (historically happened in New Guinea and Australia, went up to base-27), counting between finger joints (enables counting up to 12 on one hand), using fingers as binary digits (count up to 31 on one hand, 1023 using two).

Comment: A four fingered hand is actually perfect for counting in *hexadecimal*. Four fingers = four bits = one hex digit. They count binary with their fingers, but they fuse one handful of fingers/bits together into a single digit which they write down. That way, your dragons will be able to count to 255 with their fingers!

Comment: I think for programming and making machines they have to know base64 system as well.

Answer (score 39):

**Probably not**

While it *is* true that a Base 8 system would mean that the general public would be able to work with programming numbers and hexadecimal better, anyone who uses those number systems with any frequency very quickly acclimates to the various base systems within any programming language. There are programmers who can just offhand convert numbers to bit to hexadecimal with barely any inconvenience. So, while the general population gets a slight advantage, the part that actually works within computer sciences would be just as capable as the humans who work within our computer science fields.

Comment: This goes contrary to my own answer but is a very strong point that I can agree with, +1. I think the most hardcore programmers wouldn't feel a difference, but the dragons might have a larger programming workforce.

Comment: +1 on having a larger programming workforce, which is a distinct advantage.

Comment: I'd say you'd get a small boost in the very early computer development/usage stage, but thats only a mild one and only specific to that era.

Comment: Most of the "programming workforce" today doesn't use non-decimal numbers with any regularity. They just tell the computer numbers in base-10 digits and get them back in same, with the computer handling all the conversions. Base swapping is a tiny performance hit *in theory* but not what you'd call game-changing.

Comment: Actually, perhaps the biggest pain in base swapping these days is the impedance mismatch between binary floating point numbers and decimal floating point numbers. For example, 0.2 has no exact representation in most computers. With octal, you wouldn't have that problem... but I also don't think that would be a "game changer".

Comment: to do a quick conversion, 0.2 in octal is 2 / 8 (because base 8), which would be trivial to write out in floating-point form: 2 * 2 ^ -3. However, this isn't really helpful - you're always going to have impossible-to-represent numbers, you're always going to have fuzzy results with a (calculatable) amount of error. It would not be an advantage to count in octal, or at least not a big enough one to change things.

Comment: I agree with the conclusion, but the reasoning is off. They wouldn't have an advantage because the very purpose of computing is to offload mental work to a machine. The computer makes the mental math capabilities irrelevant.

Comment: @CarsonGraham The point of `0.2` is not so much that it isn't representable, the point is that this fact comes a total surprise to most programmers when they first witness the effects. This effect can be witnessed beautifully in some Stack Overflow questions where people think their compiler is buggy when their program tells them that `10*0.1` is not equal to `1`, etc.

Answer (score 16):

As a computer programmer and electronic engineer I can say the answer is no.

For a fairly short period in our history there was some advantage to being familiar with base 8. When computers were new and not very powerful and more importantly when software development often involved understanding the internal workings there was an advantage to base 8 because of its relation to base 2, the fundamental base for computing due to the laws of physics.

But that time period is already over. Most people programming or using computers don't use binary or octal (base 8), or if they do not to an extent where being familiar with it would be a significant help.

I've mastered base 2 and base 16 well enough that I can work right down at that low level, it wasn't particularly hard and my job is quite specialist.

Comment: Modular arithmetic with higher powers of two is still fairly important, as bignums are much more expensive. Being able to choose big enough nums trumps that fairly often though.

Answer (score 11):

Actually they might be "disadvantaged" in mathematics pre-electronics.. And by quite a lot.

Using base 10 means that you have the prime factors 2 & 5. This in turn means that any vision by a multiple of those prime factors [1/2, 1/4 = 1/(2*2), 1/5] can be written in "decimal" notation without any rounding. (Compare that to 1/3 which cannot).

Base 8 has only prime factor "2" - so 1/2, 1/4 etc can be written without rounding. But a number like "0.2" or "0.1", which can be done easily in base 10, cannot be written in base 8.

This is quite a big disadvantage pre-computer age. So much so that even for us humans there have been societies (babylonians) which actually did not use base 10. But opted for "base 30" instead (prime factors 2, 3 and 5). Being able to write out fractions without rounding is just that much an advantage.

And we still see artifacts of that in say degrees for a circle, it allows for more "integer" angles.

This is offset once you start going into formal sciences and work with floating points/errors. But similarly the advantage of easier conversion to binary is negligible: it's almost never done by hand other than for trivial stuff.

Comment: Is "This in turn means that any *vision* by a multiple" a misspelling or you mean something special? Note that if you subscribe to this idea using base 12 is probably the most plausible - you can get 1/2, 1/3, 1/4 and 1/6 of "10" (base 12) to be whole number vs. just 1/2 and 1/5 to be whole number of 10 (base 10).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this answer. 8 has 2 factors (2 and 4) and 10 has 2 factors (2 and 5). Why does them being prime or not really matter? (You pull out representing our 0.1 as being difficult for base 8, but isnt that very base-10 centric, there are plenty of numbers it's hard to represent in base 10). Obviously this argument shows why base-7 would be a nightmare, but I'm less convinced about base-8

Comment: @RichardTingle 8 has only one *prime* factor. A number system with a base with more prime factors has easier conversion between fractions and "decimals" (e.g. 1/3 cannot be represented with a finite decimal in base 10 (1/3=0.33333333...), but if you are in base 3 it is simply 1/3=0.1).

Comment: This answer implies that the optimal base pre-computer is one with as many prime factors as possible. Although I imagine that at some point the inherent complexity of the numerals would outweigh the benefits of "decimal"-fraction conversion.

Comment: @BBeast. Right but looking at which bases can represent fractions between 0 and 7 (seems a fair range, feel free to argue). 1/1: both 1/2: both 1/3: neither, 1/4: Base-8, 1/5: Base 10, 1/6: neither, 1/7: neither. So a score of 3/7 for both of them. What is it I'm missing here? Obviously 4 isnt prime, but why does that matter

Comment: @RichardTingle If you allow finite decimal representations rather than single digit decimals, the score is 4 to 3 for Base 10 vs Base 8. But I concede that the difference is small. While the difference between, say, Base 30 and Base 8 would be bigger (as paul23 alludes to), the question is comparing a world with Base 10 to Base 8.

Comment: @BBeast base 12 was standard in Europe for most of the medieval times when it came to trading amounts of items: dozen, gross, etc

Comment: So you're saying that humanity has been disadvantaged by using base-10 instead of base-30 or base-360 for all numbers?  How much more could we have accomplished by now if we had used base-30 or base-360?  If the Babylonians were mathematically superior, why didn't their system persist?

Comment: I don't think that being able to divide cleanly by 5 adds any value if you can't divide cleanly by 3. We only tend to use factors of 5 because we use factors of 10, but if our culture were using base 8, we wouldn't use any significant amount of factors 5, and by consequence wouldn't see any reason to include the factor 5 into our number system. Having factor 3 in the base would be nice, that would indeed reduce some troubles that we have with base 10, but the factor 5 is mostly useless from a mathematical point of view.

Comment: @RichardTingle please don't state things you haven't tried yourself - what you can divide through is based on the prime factors: in base 10 you can *obviously* take 1/4th: it's 0.25 exactly. Just like you can take 1/20 (=1/(2*2*5)) = 0.05. In base 8 this would be a continued fraction. Base 12 has thus no advantage over base 6, except that you keep numbers "smaller", base 6 you quickly need a lot of signs for a simple number.

Comment: @paul23 All of that should be in your answer, not in a comment

Comment: @RichardTingle uh that's just reiteration of grade school math (or when do you learn long division? - if you do long division in a numeric system you quickly discover it) trivial and I find it weird to explicitly state it.

Comment: Its your answer, so ultimately its up to you, but I think its a worse answer for it

Answer (score 5):

At this moment I imagine many of my peers here at the site might be tempted to close this question as off-topic.

I'll just say that I spent a number of years in college for a bachelor degree in Computer Science. I saw time and again people dropping out of CS because they could not wrap their heads around it. Many were the challenges, and understanding math in bases other than 10 was a huge factor. I personally know a couple handful people who failed 2nd semester subjects because they could not understand how $1 + 1 = 10$. And they were counting on their fingers. Seriously. To this day I believe that if you cannot read time on a clock like this, you cannot get a degree in CS:

[image: A binary clock]

A sentient species with an octal number base might probably have a much easier time converting to binary and hexadecimal, which are common in low level programming (some the hardest forms of programming come into this category).

I propost a challenge here, watch this video starting on the 2:22 mark: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DfCJgC2zezw&t=142s

Did it instantly make sense to you? If so, you're probably a Math or CS student or graduate - or you belong to a species with eight fingers with a base 8 numeral system. If you struggle with it for more than two minutes, the good news is that you will probably never have to pay for expensive books about C++.

**For clarification:** I'm not saying these guys would have an easier time programming in octal. I'm saying they would have an easier time understanding binary and hexadecimal, which is what keeps some people out of math-intensive courses in the area of computing. I'm not implying that when programming you do it all the time.

Comment: *" failed 2nd semester subjects because they could not understand how 1+1=10"*  Perhaps they should introduce it in the first semester then - or even make it a pre-requisite. This would be an effective early filter for people who just aren't suited to the subject.

Comment: I think you greatly overestimate the necessity of understanding octal or hex in CS.  Or reading a clock like that: I can't (at least without reading the man page), yet I have advanced degrees and a fairly successful career.  (Though I admit I still get irritated by people who use octal unnecessarily, as in chmod permissions.

Comment: @jamesqf that clock doesn't require a man page.

Comment: @Renan 1100  1111 -> 12 15 but if you were from a culture that reads right to left it would be 11  111100 -> 3  56 so really only trivial if the functioning matches your expectations. There are other possible meanings too. We just assume it's a binary watch ...

Comment: Also, 2nd semester college? We did the various bases in high school math, only had a very brief refresher starting Uni. If you pitched up to a college/uni CS class not understanding binary you'd better catch up fast or you were ever so slightly screwed.

Comment: @Renan: EVERYTHING requires a man page :-)  Even if it's as simple as "This device displays time as two binary numbers.  Filled circles are ones, empty ones are zeros. And you're SOL if you want to use a 24 hour clock."

Comment: Note that in reality 1+1 = 0. If you don't get *that* you are in trouble in real world programming (may be fine for pure CS so). :)

Comment: -1 I don't see anyone proposing to close this as off-topic or any reason why it would be. Your answer doesn't really address the question except for a bunch of gatekeeping "if you can't read this esoteric watch desgin you're not a coder"; "programming at a low level is the hardest".

Comment: Who uses octal in programming?  Hexidecimal?  Sure, all the time.  Binary?  Yeah, here and there.  Base 36 and 256 are somewhat common as well.  But I've basically never felt the need to use octal for anything, even in languages that have built-in support for it.

Comment: A lot of irrelevant stuff in this answer. Why would a programmer need to quickly convert binary in their head? Why would you be doing octal operations in c++? I'm sure there are specific applications that would require it, but general programming operates on much higher level concepts. Part of the point of computers is that only a few people have to truly understand the principles at play, and others can make use of their work while focusing on their specific application. A population that can mentally to octal math won't have any sort of edge in programming.

Comment: @David258 He said "you cannot get a degree in CS". This is not the same as being a coder since many programmers don't have a CS degree.  But, if you are studying the science behind computers, understanding binary is foundational.

Comment: @Harabeck Code optimisation.  It often make the difference between a 1 millisecond load time and a 1000 millisecond load time.  Sure loading eight times as fast may not seem like that big of a deal with such small time increments, but if it's a task that has to be repeated enough, it can lead to some considerable lag reduction.

Comment: @Nosajimiki That doesn't add to what I said. The very few people that work on that very low level make that optimization once, and then everyone else benefits from then on. That's the nature of good programming.

Comment: @harabeck not just low level programming. I get paid a lot of money to fix bugs caused when companies paid less than a lot of money to developers who could care less about proper text encoding and parsing, which is not so low level but still requires people to know how to handle bytes and to know that they have different minimum and maximum values in different languages. I also see a lot of people making videogames these days and as far as I can tell being able to comb bits in this market takes you to good places.

Comment: @Harabeck  It's like the difference between imperial and international systems.  For every day use, it may not matter, but a population that understands the international system can do the hard stuff better. So, a really smart person can calculate the volume of a foot of 4.5 gauge wire, but it's much easier to find the volume of a meter of 4.5mm wire since everything converts more easily.

Comment: For example, in mysql, a 16-bit text field can contain 65,536 - 1 characters.  This is a hard ideal scope to remember so we use TEXT to always make a 16-bit text field, but in Octal, any rounded number will give you a power of 2; so, instead of always using TEXT which is often too big or TINYTEXT which is often too small, programmers would be more likely to use VARCHAR(1000) or  VARCHAR(10000) and still get a full power of 2 scope.

Comment: "*To this day I believe that if you cannot read time on a clock like this, you cannot get a degree in CS*" I disagree. One can learn to read this clock if they are taught. No one is a professor from the start.

Comment: @SnackExchange you should naturslly learn how to read that clock during a comp-sci course. Some people just couldn't be taught.

Comment: Well, you used the word "some" now. So the generalization in your first sentence is debunked by yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematics is very abstract. In principle you can choose your own base which fits your system best.

In our every day's life we use a base of 10. Why? Because it is easy to learn. We use 10 fingers for counting. In the old Babylonian days they used a base of 60 (12 joints of the 4 fingers on one hand, counting with the thumb and 5 fingers on the other hand for counting the 'overflows' of 12). Computers use a base of 2, because they only know 'ON' and 'OFF'.

Whats the advantage of a large number of symbols, i.e. a bigger base? Bigger numbers are easier (require less 'space') to write down. 512 just needs 3 digits in a decimal system, but needs 10 digits in binary (10 0000 0000). The disadvantage is you need more symbols (like 60 different when using the babylonian sexagesimal system).

But what about understanding math? Have you ever taken a 'real' lecture on mathematics, like on university level? You will soon understand that 'real' math has little to do with calculations. Calculations - regardless of the base used - yield the same result. In some situations it is easier to use a base of 2, in some it is 10. You can even transform equations (integrals for example) from 'cartesian coordinates' to polar ones, which often results in a more familiar and easier equation.

I'm sure that the numeral system used does not influence how good we or another species understand mathematics or builds machines.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that dragon 'hands' would provide much more trouble than cultural familiarity with the number system would offset. Claws may be great for battle but for manipulating tiny things are a huge disadvantage.

Comment: The question doesn't say anything about the the size, shape, retractibility, or any other details about the dragons' claws. It doesn't even say if they have claws on their hands. It does however state that the dragons are anthropomorphic, and thus their hands are quite likely just about as dexterous as human hands.

Answer (score 0):

With only 8 fingers perhaps their keyboards would be smaller.  That would leave more space on their desks for napkins to capture the designs brilliant new ideas.

Answer (score 0):

There would be some advantage, but only marginal and for other reasons.

There was a time in our history when we had [computers working in base 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_computer) - in addition to computers working in base 2. Those were marketed as more suitable for business and data processing tasks, as opposed for scientific data crunching (no rounding artifacts when converting to and from base 2).

Fast forward to early microprocessor era - many CPUs featured [BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) support on silicon, because it was widely believed the alternate base 10 representation would be useful for exact arithmetic (again, financial calculations, but also faster number conversion for printing etc.).

Then the software caught on, and by today, practically everything is done in software. Even modern [x86 BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_BCD_opcode) is microcoded and thus likely much slower than native silicon implementation could be, but it is just not important anymore, apart for backward compatibility.

So, back to your civilization, there would be a period of time where the equivalent of our decimal computers would not have to be developed, freeing effort and resources for other development. And early CPUs would be marginally cheaper and designed faster, and having less transistors (or equivalently, having additional features while having the same number of transistors).

Note that the question asks about electronics - thus the speculation about the advantages of binary or binary-coded octal for early mechanical computations are off topic.

Also note that the number of fingers is related, but not essential for the number system of the civilization. After all, we humans use remnants of old Babylonian base 60 (clocks), used a parallel base 12 system at least somewhat (dozen, gross, great gross) and there were [even languages with base 8 number system](http://linguistics.berkeley.edu/%7Eavelino/Avelino_2006.pdf). But the Indo-European base 10 won, for reasons unrelated to the number system.